# Calendar returns wrong week

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar, dayofweek, java.util.calendar

So I need to get time in milliseconds for Monday of this week and time in milliseconds of Sunday for this week and with code below it worked fine till I installed app on emulator and if I set time to Sunday it returns `Jun 18 - Jun 24`, but on Samsung Galaxy s5 it returns `Jun 11 - Jun 17 <- this is how it should show` Am I doing something wrong?

`getMondayTime` method returns time in milliseconds for monday

```
private fun getMondayTime(): Long{
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    calendar.firstDayOfWeek = Calendar.MONDAY
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY)
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)

    return calendar.timeInMillis
}
```

`getSundayTime` returns time in milliseconds for sunday

```
private fun getSundayTime(): Long {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    calendar.firstDayOfWeek = Calendar.MONDAY
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY)
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)

    return calendar.timeInMillis
}
```

Here I'm putting all this time into places

```
fun generateWeek(): Week{
    val format = SimpleDateFormat("MMM d", Locale.ENGLISH)
    val mondayTime = getMondayTime()
    val sundayTime = getSundayTime()

    val label = "${format.format(mondayTime)} - ${format.format(sundayTime)}"
    return Week(label, mondayTime, sundayTime)
}
```

Comment: A time zone issue? If you are running the code on Sunday (late afternoon or evening?) on an emulator that uses a time zone where it’s already Monday, I guess you will get the wrong week that you observed.

Comment: Consider throwing the classes `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` away. They are long outmoded and poorly designed and `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead you may add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time

I am sorry I cannot write Kotlin (if that’s your language?) so I will have to trust you to translate from Java. The modern solution is:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d", Locale.ENGLISH);
    // Time zone is crucial for controlling which week we get.
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Lower_Princes");
    WeekFields wf = WeekFields.ISO; // Monday is first day of week
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(zone);
    ZonedDateTime mondayTime = today.with(wf.dayOfWeek(), 1).atStartOfDay(zone);
    ZonedDateTime sundayTime = today.with(wf.dayOfWeek(), 7)
            .atTime(LocalTime.of(22, 0))
            .atZone(zone);
    String label = mondayTime.format(dateFormatter) + " - " + sundayTime.format(dateFormatter);
    System.out.println("Label:                 " + label);
    System.out.println("Monday time in millis: " + mondayTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
    System.out.println("Sunday time in millis: " + sundayTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

Running just now (Monday) this printed:

```
Label:                 Jun 18 - Jun 24
Monday time in millis: 1529294400000
Sunday time in millis: 1529892000000
```

At time of writing it is still Sunday in very few time zones in the Pacific. So I also tried one of those:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Pacific/Niue");
```

Then I got last week:

```
Label:                 Jun 11 - Jun 17
Monday time in millis: 1528714800000
Sunday time in millis: 1529312400000
```

So specifying the correct time zone is crucial for getting the week you want. I suspect that this was the issue in your question: if your emulator is set to using a time zone where it was already Monday when you ran your code, it would give you the coming week, as you observed.

I am using and recommending `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

If you are opposed to depending on an external library, even a future-proof one like ThreeTenABP — I mean, it’s developed by the same folks that developed `java.time` for Java and it only contains functionality that will also be included in core Java once you upgrade to API level 26 or higher — in that case you can probably solve your issue by passing the correct `TimeZone` object to the `Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone)` method (I haven’t tried). `TimeZone` is one more of the outdated date and time classes.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [`Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone)` method documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance-java.util.TimeZone-)